# I forgot my account credentials and now I’m locked out - what can I do to recover my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I know I’ve been out of the site for a while, but I’m the user [DT Cooper](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/51013/dt-cooper) and I was locked out of my account. I never saved said account, and now I’ve been locked out. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You never registered your account because there is no DT Cooper in the database.

Comment: @Vincent You just don't see it when searching because it's unregistered. You can find the account [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/51013/dt-cooper).

Comment: I would strongly, strongly, *strongly*, **strongly** recommend creating a registered account, given your continuous use of the site.

Comment: @HDE 226868: How do I do that?

Comment: @DTCooper2 See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/274942 and the links therein.

Comment: Kudos to all that helped this guy even though the question is off topic in this site. No one dared to even close this, I want to tell you guys you did a good job! No sarcasm intended.

Answer (score 8):

You can look at the question [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) on MSE and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233/352819).

Basically you go to the contact button at the bottom of this page and then describe exactly what your problem is.

On WorldBuilding you visit this site, which describes the exact process: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

Comment: Do you know if the process works for more than 2 accounts?

Comment: @Aify I never had to go through the process myself, let alone with more than two accounts. I guess if you go to the contact page where you have to write a text anyway you can theoretically get an "unlimited" amount of accounts merged. Whether the community managers that will receive your request will grant it is written on a different page. In this case it looks like recovering the main account seems to be the main concern, which means the user just needs to visit the last link in my answer, enter their e-mail address and click "send", which will leave other accounts alone.